# How to convert object in DataFrame to string

Tags: python

I want to convert an object in a DataFrame to a string in Python.

I tried str() but it still shows the datatype as "object"...

```
str(dpd)
```

...and I want to convert it to a string.

Comment: `dpd = str(dpd)` - str doesn't work in place, it returns the new value, so you need to assign it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

`object` in pandas is same as `str`, so you don't need to change anything.

**Longer Answer:**

Pandas `object` is `str`, how do you know:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','b','c'], 'b':['x', 'y', 'z']})
>>> df.dtypes
a    object
b    object
dtype: object
>>> df = df.astype(str)
>>> df.dtypes
a    object
b    object
dtype: object
>>>
```

If it's integer:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})
>>> df.dtypes
a    int64
b    int64
dtype: object
>>> df = df.astype(str)
>>> df.dtypes
a    object
b    object
dtype: object
>>>
```

It changes.

Comment: e.g.my string is 056026000000000000000000000000000000025000000000000000 but it shows value in excel as 5.6026E+52. what to do?